# Absolute positioned image in responsive design

Tags: html, css, image, positioning, absolute

I am in need of some assistance.

I am currently working on a site that is going to be responsive.
Will post a link to an image of the psd of the site so you have an idea
 what it is supposed to be like.
[image: Link to screenshot of the site what it will look like]

[Link to the site itself](http://www.fishbone-designs.be/school/stage/index.html)
the site has a width of 1200px as you scale the site you will see that the boat will do nothing

Now to the problem.

the problem lays with the boat this img is 1019x1732 and is positioned absolute. And needs to be so because i have to use the z-index to be able to position it above some other divs for it is rather big.
I have tried to put it in as a background-image and as an img tag with a relative div around it. but nothing happens.
My appolagies if my question is a hard to understand. have a hard time explaining problems to other people, it always makes more sence in my head.
Here is my code:
my html

```
<div id="wrapperHero">

        <div id="hero">

            <p>The "Banarly Group" has been operating<br>
                in Nigerian, Gabonese and Cameroon waters<br>
                since 1995.
            </p>
            <div id="circle">
                <p>a fleet of<br> 
                    <span class="number">24</span><span class="trawler">trawlers</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="boat">
            <img src="img/BAN_herofg.png" alt="boat">
        </div>

    </div>
```

My css:

```
#wrapperHero {
width: 100%;
background-image: url(../img/BAN_herobg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
min-height: 795px;
margin-top: -23px;}

#hero {
max-width: 1200px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;}

#boat {
background-image: url(../img/BAN_herofg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
right: -6%;
top: 240px;}

#circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 18.3333%;
min-height: 220px;
background-color: #fff;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
float: right;
margin: -230px 21.6666% 0 0;}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z30K.png):

Comment: You haven't explained your problem, only how the site works.

Comment: ok my bad then haha the problem is that the boat does not scale along just stands there in the corner

Comment: And after a certain viewport size even dissapears, i tried to solve this with putting the image inside a div that is relative this does make the image move alond but only after a certain viewport size.

Comment: Thanks alot everybody. For the quick responses and quick answer. And my appolagies for the vaguely asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background-size ,  background-position-x with different media :)

```
 #boat {
 background-size: 590px;
 background-position-x: 79px;
}

 @media (min-width: 450px) and (max-width: 960px) {
     #boat {background-size: //use different size;
     background-position-x://use different size;}
}
```

Comment: I will try this out. Do the background-size and min- max-width need to be in % or can they be in px.

Comment: not necessarily but you can if you want too , its all about your need :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, here's what you should do:

remove the `background-image` property from `#boat`
create `<img src="img/BAN_herofg">` inside
set `max-width: 100%` to `<img>`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Use css media queries to solve your problem...**

ex:

```
  @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
  }
```

Comment: Yea i thought of this aswell but am i then going be making a media querie for every screen size because on my screen the boat is in the right position but on bosses screen wich is bigger, the boat is more to the right